# notfiy-send not showing up with upstart

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart

Problem : notify-send command is not showing up notification even though the log file is created.

Contents of **/home/user/test**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test job, reporting...'
while :
do
notify-send 'This is a simple notification Sir'
sleep 30
done
```

Contents of **/etc/init/myjob.conf**

```
description "test job"
start on runlevel [2345]
exec /home/sajal/test
```

To check for any syntax error :

```
$ init-checkconf myjob.conf
```

In order to run the above .config file i used :

```
$ sudo start myjob
```

[image]

to view the contents of log generated :

```
$ sudo gedit /var/log/upstart/myjob.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Upstart problem at all. You are trying to send [Desktop Notifications](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html#introduction) using [system job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-job) which is executed in an environment having no refference to you desktop session namely it is missing `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `DISPLAY` along with other environmental variables.

You could use us [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) instead (recommended) or gain understanding on Linux permissions, session and environments and define needed enviromental variables in your system job configuration file. You might find some useful hints in those two threads related to sending desktop notifications from system cron job. [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1727148) and [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1533494)